# How to make this code work in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
class Event(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    def __init__(self):
        self.type = self.get_full_type()

    @classmethod
    def get_full_type(cls):
        return None

    def as_dict(self):
        return self.__dict__


class BaseEvent(Event, metaclass=ABCMeta):

    SUB_TYPE = ''

    @classmethod
    def get_base_type(cls):
        return super().get_full_type()

    @classmethod
    def get_full_type(cls):
        base_type = cls.get_base_type()
        if base_type:
            return '.'.join([base_type, cls.SUB_TYPE])
        else:
            return cls.SUB_TYPE
```

Here you can see my attempt to make class that represents some abstract event. What is crucial here is the ability to distinguish event types. So every event has it's type and it's base type. Full type is base type + subtype.

This gives the ability to define new event type like this

```
class MockEvent(BaseEvent):

    SUB_TYPE = 'mock'

    def __init__(self, some_object):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.some_object = some_object
```

So the full type is mirroring the class hierarchy ClassA.ClassB.ClassC etc. I think you get the point.

Unfortunately this is not working with python 2

```
class Event(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    SUB_TYPE = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = self.get_full_type()

    @classmethod
    def get_base_type(cls):
        return None

    @classmethod
    def get_full_type(cls):
        base_type = cls.get_base_type()
        if base_type:
            return '.'.join([base_type, cls.SUB_TYPE])
        else:
            return cls.SUB_TYPE

    def as_dict(self):
        return self.__dict__


class BaseEvent(Event):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    SUB_TYPE = ''

    @classmethod
    def get_base_type(cls):
        return super(cls.__class__, cls).get_full_type()
```

> File "/opt/leos/code/event_service/events/EventBus.py", line 38, in
>   get_base_type
>       return super(cls.**class**, cls).get_full_type()
>   AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'get_full_type'

How can I make this work?

Comment: When does it give that error?

Comment: Make `super().get_full_type()` to `super(self.__class__, self).get_full_type()`?

Comment: @thefourtheye I've modified the question to answer that.

Comment: @adarsh Where do you see the super().get_full_type()?

Comment: In the first code block, in `BaseEvent` class, in `get_base_type`

Comment: @adarsh : `super(self.__class__, self)` is not the proper way to use `super()` in Python 2 - if it was, `super()` wouldn't need the reference to current class ("current" : class where the function is defined, not class on which it's called).

Comment: @adarsh It's a python 3 code. Python 2 code is below that. Also as you can see it's a class method, so no self would be available there. The problem with python 2 is that super doesn't return superclass it's probably just somehow doing abstract method resolution.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers why do you think that super(self.__class__, self) is wrong in python 2? It's working perfectly AFAIK.

Comment: @user1685095 : `self.__class__` is the class on which the method is called. What `super()` needs to correctly resolve the mro is the class in which the method is *defined*. Else there would be no need to pass both the class and instance, `super()` could get it by itself from the instance.

Comment: @user1685095: also and FWIW, `super()` does indeed not return "the superclass" - it returns a `super()` object (yes, it's a type, not a function) that indeed resolves the correct "next" class in the mro, according the class in which the method is defined and the class (or instance of) on which it's called. Remember that Python supports multiple inheritance, so there's not (not necessarily) one single "superclass". It's all documented FWIW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Event(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    def __init__(self):
        self.type = self.get_full_type()

    @classmethod
    def get_full_type(cls):
        return None

    def as_dict(self):
        return self.__dict__


class BaseEvent(Event):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    SUB_TYPE = None

    @classmethod
    def get_full_type(cls):
        super_type = cls.get_super_type()
        base_type = super_type.get_full_type()
        if base_type:
            return '.'.join([base_type, cls.SUB_TYPE])
        else:
            return cls.SUB_TYPE

    @classmethod
    def get_super_type(cls):
        return cls.__base__
```

I needed to get the base type automatically. Without mentioning current class in super(currectClass, self) So I used cls.**base** and it's working  ok.